# Inserting multiple values into a single MySQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

Using HeidiSQL. Trying to seed DB with new test data. Keep getting `Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`. "test" is a brand new table with just an `auto_increment` "id" col and a column called "person_id". This really could not be simpler but....

```
insert into test (person_id) values ('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', 
'2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', etc 26)
```

Had a DB corruption before. Is that possible or am I just going blind?

Comment: If you're trying to insert multiple rows, put parentheses around each row: `insert into test (person_id) values ('1'), ('1'), ('1'), etc.`

Comment: Ed thanks so much don't think I ever knew that.Yep worked fine Thanks What a wasted hour :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extended insert syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values1), (values2), (values3), etc...
                                     ^--record #1            ^--record #3
                                                 ^--record #2
```

You're trying to insert ONE SINGLE record, with a few zillion fields in it. Note the `(), (), ()` format...